# PyhtonInterpreter all imports are failing

Tags: java, python, jython

Im using [jython 2.7.0](http://www.jython.org/) and everything is working except one thing: I cant import anything. I do the following:

```
PythonInterpreter.initialize(props, System.getProperties(), new String[]{script.getParams().toJSON(), script.getContext().toJSON()});
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

interpreter.execfile(script.getPath());
interpreter.exec("import sys");
interpreter.exec("import json");
interpreter.exec("import random");

PyObject answerEvent = interpreter.eval("json.loads(sys.argv[0])");
PyObject answerContext = interpreter.eval("json.loads(sys.argv[1])");
PyObject answerResult = interpreter.eval("json.dumps(handler(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1]))");

System.out.println("=====================================================================");
System.out.println(answerEvent.toString());
System.out.println(answerContext.toString());
System.out.println(answerResult.toString());
System.out.println("=====================================================================");
```

And it really does not matter which import I run, I always get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named json
```

or

```
Import Error: No module named random
```

How do I get the imports working.

**EDIT**

Sorry, my information was not completely correct: `import sys` is working without a problem. The other two imports arent.

**EDIT 2**

I tried a recommended workaround described [here in the last post](http://bugs.jython.org/issue2355) but the result was the same.

Comment: Set your JYTHONPATH to whatever place your Jython jar file resides in.

Comment: Python and jython itself is working. If I just run a simple hello world without importing something it is working fine.

Comment: If you use the standalone version of Jython, I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with the following:

```
interpreter.exec("import sys");
interpreter.exec("sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7')");
interpreter.exec("import random");
interpreter.exec("import json");
```

I needed to point to the lib folder of python 2.7 (But I still dont know why)